# check date between two dates or NULL in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to `check date` in `between two dates` or can pass as a `NULL`
using stored proc

code

```
declare @fromDate date = null
declare @toDate date = null

select * from Mytable 
where date betweeen @fromDate and @toDate OR NULL (how to check for both parameters)
```

I have other 2 more parameters so irrespective with date result should be displayed.
if @todate and @fromDate is NULL

please help.

Comment: if @toDate is null, what results do you need?

Comment: I have other 2 more parameters so irrespactive with date result should be displayed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with coalesce function as below

```
declare @fromDate date = null
declare @toDate date = null

select * from Mytable 
where date between coalesce(@fromDate,date) and coalesce(@toDate,date)
```

Comment: @parado Testing this wouldn't work for dates equal to the `@fromDate` or `@toDate` only strictly < or >. - So the `@fromDate` would have to be - 1 day or toDate + 1 day. - if i'm reading this right.

Comment: @Pakk I don't know your case, but I checked above solution - It works

Comment: @Parado I've since found out why - my fault. My dates were looking for Date + '00:00:00:0000' through Date + '00:00:00:0000'. - I was missing the timeSpan. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much convert your English to SQL:

```
where (date is null or date betweeen @fromDate and @toDate)
```

Comment: Not sure but I think OP means parameters can be null not the date field.

Comment: That syntax not working i have used coalesce instead IS NULL  :)

Answer (score 0):

When searching for a better solution than `"between"` with `"coalesce"` i found this thread:

- firebird SQL
- param is never NULL
- createdatum is never NULL
- offdatum can be NULL - for obvious reasons ;)

Initial solution:

```
where
    X = :X
    AND
    cast(:QryDateTime as DATE) between
      createdatum and coalesce(offdatum, cast(:QryDateTime as DATE))
```

problem there was a little tricky: when using "now" as value for QryDateTime there was (very rarely) no result found - even if there should exist one

Problem was that now is evaluated every time separately and obviously not in the left-to-right order.

I finally changed it to:

```
where
    X = :X
    AND
    iif(offdatum is null, 1, iif(offdatum > cast(:QryDateTime as DATE), 1, 0)) = 1
    AND
    cast(:QryDateTime as DATE) > createdatum
```